# Can't setup netcfg service in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I already add this service to startup with `systemctl enable netcfg`,

here's contents of `/etc/conf.d/network`,

```
NETWORKS=(eth0 eth1)
WIRED_INTERFACE="eth0"
WIRELESS_INTERFACE="wlan0"
AUTO_PROFILES=(eth0 eth1)
```

And contents of netcfg.service:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netcfg.service 
[Unit]
Description=Netcfg multi-profile daemon
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/netcfg-daemon start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/netcfg-daemon stop
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

journalctl logs of netcfg:

```
Oct 29 XXXXXX localhost netcfg-daemon[182]: No recorded netcfg state to restore
Oct 29 XXXXXX localhost systemd[1]: netcfg.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 29 XXXXXX localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start Netcfg multi-profile daemon.
Oct 29 XXXXXX localhost systemd[1]: Unit netcfg.service entered failed state
```

It doesn't work (works randomly?), the output says `netcfg` failed, but invoke it manually works, why?

[image]

Comment: what is the content of your /etc/conf.d/netcfg, and what does the multi-profile looks like ?

Comment: @slubman updated

Comment: What does journalctl show for netcfg and could you paste what netcfg.service contents are?

Comment: @Salil all pasted

Comment: Sorry, did not find anything revealing. If you just want to use ethernet interface, I am wondering why don't you just use dhcpd instead. I have stopped using netcfg even for wireless; wpa_supplicant and dhcpd works fine for me.

Comment: Same problem [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150076): "netcfg.service requires an array of profile names in `/etc/conf.d/netcfg NETWORKS=(...)` - have you set that up? Also, I'm curious - if you're already using net-auto-wireless.service, why do you want netcfg.service?"

Comment: @Quits no wireless...it's a VM, and NETWORKS() array are set, see the head of my question

Answer (score 3):

`netcfg` is deprecated. Upgrade to `netctl` and try again.

Comment: This question was asked in 2012, when netcfg was not deprecated.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman yes, but it's worth noting for e.g. people coming from Google. Plus, it gets it off the unanswered list.

Comment: ensuing Meta discussion: http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1340/will-someone-tell-me-if-this-answer-mine-is-too-cheeky